# Trying to removes spaces between initials in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a column that contains a persons name and I need to extract it to pass to another system but I need to remove the spaces but only from between the initials
for example I might have

`Mr A B Bloggs` and I want `Mr AB Bloggs` or

`Mrs A B C Bloggs` and I want `Mrs ABC Bloggs`

As there are millions of records in the table I wont know how many initials there are or indeed if there are any initials. All I know is the prefix (Mr, Mrs etc) will be more than 1 character and so will the surname. I've tried using `trim`, `replace`, `charindex` but obviously not in the right combination. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You should include the DBMS you're using.

Comment: This _might_ be possible with a regular expression, but only certain databases would support it.

Comment: Are there multi-word surnames in your data set (e.g. `Mr S van der Valk`)?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever I'm assuming he just wants to aggregate a bunch of single letters occurring in the middle of the name.  Maybe I'm wrong.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen - I'm just exploring alternative formulations. E.g. if the data is simple, it might be transformable to "replace all but the first and last spaces in the string with an empty string"

Comment: Yet another ugly CTE.

Comment: @DuduMarkovitz That would assume his database supports CTE (e.g. it isn't MySQL, SQLite, etc.).

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: It sql server 2012 and there are multi word surnames but just initials for middle names

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen - charindex

Comment: It's not something I'd do in the database, but I'd create an application in a more appropiate code layer, pull in data, do the manipulation and save it again. _IF_ you _really_ need to do it in SQL, I'd make a function that loops over each character in a text string via a while loop, and does logic based work - and then call that function per name in an update

Comment: @AllanS.Hansen This might be possible to do with a carefully crafted regex, but the DB would need to support it.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I know, but the tools for manipulating strings and error handling and debugging you get in - for example .NET or Java - will surely be much more easy to work with than trying to craft it in SQL - even with a regex.

Comment: _IF you really need to do it in MS SQL SERVER_ I'd make a CLR Function for regexp support.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately SQL server does not support regex. You have two options:

1. Use .Net in CLR to perform the transformation. This link explains how to implement regex in SQL server using CLR: https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/clr-assembly-regex-functions-for-sql-server-by-example/.
2. Other option is to use a cursor to iterate through all the reocords and transform each entry. This may be slow for a large table. For example, you could write a function that returns location of spaces surrounded by single letters and then remove them. The trick is not to remove them until you have recorded all of them, and then remove them from right to left to avoid the location changing.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
declare @test varchar(100)='Mrs A B C Bloggs'
select (substring (@test,0,charindex(' ',@test)))+' '+ 
        replace(replace(replace(substring(@test,len((substring (@test,0,charindex(' ',@test))))+1,len(@test)),
        (substring (@test,0,charindex(' ',@test))),''),reverse((substring (reverse(@test),0,charindex(' ',reverse(@test))))),''),' ','')
         +' '+reverse((substring (reverse(@test),0,charindex(' ',reverse(@test)))))
```

Comment: running this at the moment, will let you know what it looks like

Comment: That removes the spaces between all words, I need to be specific about initials of 1 character